# Launching exported .app (from archive) does nothing OSX

Tags: macos, export, xcode7

I've followed the directions from: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingApplicationsOutside/DistributingApplicationsOutside.html

I am able to run and archive the application, but when I attempt to open the application (double clicking and control clicking -> open) Nothing happens. The app doesn't seem to run and I get no error messages.

Any direction on to what to do would be great, even if I could get an error message that would be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: Check for messages related to your app in `Console.app`...